# Java, throwing an exception versus using try/catch?

Tags: java

What are the rules for using try/catch statements, as opposed to just throwing an Exception and within the method declaration adding "throws Exception" ?

Should the try/catch just be for the client code and the "throws Exception" be within the API methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general logic with checked exceptions is - if you can take measures in the exceptional situation, do so. Otherwise - rethrow up.

Note that `throws Exception` should be avoided, but I'll assume you mean `throw SomeException` - be as concrete as possible.

The real benefit of checked exceptions is limited, but they are overused. That leads to (in many cases justified) simply wrapping them in an unchecked exception:

```
} catch (CheckedException ex) {
     throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
}
```

I've shared my thoughts on the matter [here](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=316).

Answer (score 0):

You throw an exception when you want another method higher up to handle it. You try/catch if you're expecting an exception and you want to handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to handle the exception and it makes sense to handle it, then handle it, otherwise pass it through with `throws`.

- DO NOT catch an exception and ignore it, unless that REALLY makes sense.
- DO NOT catch an exception and force exit -- if the error is "fatal" signal a `FatalError`.
- Think twice before you catch an exception and just set a return code -- doing so loses a lot of useful information about the specific error.

Of course, keep in mind that if you're extending a class and overriding an existing method you must match the method prototype of the original method.  This may require you to handle exceptions you'd rather just let pass through.